# Curly braces notation with vectors as elements

Tags: calculus, notation, vectors

In a paper by [Camescasse et al.: "Bistable buckled beam: Elastica modeling and analysis of static actuation"](http://www.lmm.jussieu.fr/%7Efernande/resources/2013-IJSS.pdf) in equation 23, they use a (to me) unknown notation for which i can't find any good resources or other examples from related papers.

$$
\left\{ \frac{d\mathcal{U}}{ds} \right\}_{G(s)}
=
\frac{d}{ds} \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{\vec{q}(s)}{\vec{p}(s)}_{G(s)}
$$

I don't know what concept they express, or why there are two vectors stacked on top of each other on the right side of the equation.

They use that notation later on as well in an integral, in equation (28), rendering me unable to follow the calculations.

Comment: Maybe it is [Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) and the author used curly brackets in order to avoid (?) misunderstanding with braces used for vectors ?

Comment: That would be unusual and should warrant a comment in the surrounding text imo, but could just as well be the case. What would the $G(s)$ in the index mean in that case? Gradient at the point $G(s)$?

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure, but my best guess is that the authors simply grouped these vectors for concise formulas, with no particular semantics attached.